# Flexbox fit height of row while overflowing right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I want to create a layout like the below:

[image]

The left column has a specified width (e.g. 30%). The right column has any number of children, which overflow to the right. These children should fit the height of the left column, without increasing the width of the parent.

At the moment, if there aren't enough children either the height of the right column gets increased so the children take up the full width, or all children fit the width so aren't tall enough.

It needs to:

- Maintain aspect ratio of all children
- Fit height of left column exactly
- Overflow horizontally

```css
.container-a,
.container-b {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container-a {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.flex-child img {
  width: 100%;
}

.first-child {
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-a">
  <div class="flex-child first-child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="container-b">
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random">
        Some text content
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random">
        Some text content
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random">
        Some text content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this layout work, I think you'll need a height constraint and a combination of flex properties.

```css
.container-a,
.container-b {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container-a {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px; /* limits images' intrinsic heights */
}

.flex-child {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.container-b>.flex-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;  /* disable flex-shrink */
  flex-direction: column; /* stack items */
}

.flex-child img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0; /* override min-height: auto default */
}

.first-child {
  flex: 1 0 40%; /* equivalent to max-width: 40%, but also disables flex-shrink */
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; } /* factor borders and padding into lengths */
```

```html
<div class="container-a">
  <div class="flex-child first-child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="container-b">
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random"> Some text content
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random"> Some text content
      </div>
      <div class="flex-child">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450?random"> Some text content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```